# ASP.NET Razor Pages - Angular dist files not copying to bin folder

Tags: asp.net-core, angular-cli, razor-pages, visual-studio-2022, csproj

I'm encounterring issues where only JSON files are copied on the `bin` folder and the static files generated from Angular CLI's `ng build` are excluded on VS 2022 Solution build.

is there any reason why it does that?

is there a way to opt out from it?

Comment: Hi @aj go, have you checked this github issue here: https://github.com/tonysneed/Demo.VSCode.TypeScript/issues/2

Comment: Hi @Rena - I believe, the issue there is different from the issue I'm experiencing, I am able to see the dist files created by angular CLI..but when VS 2022 starting to build the project files including the files generated from angular CLI, it only copies JSON files of the angular app to the bin folder..